# why does noscript move into body tag instead of head tag

Tags: php, apache, xampp

On my **PHP** project,
I put **noscript** tag in **head** tag like below..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <noscript></noscript>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a **template** file which a php script gets and renders.

the **PHP** script is like below..

```
$file = file_get_contents( $templatePath ); 
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true; // not working
$dom->encoding = 'UTF-8'; 

libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
$dom->loadHTML( mb_convert_encoding($file, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8') , LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING );
libxml_clear_errors();

echo $dom->saveHtml();
```

in localhost, it displays as it is. so it is ok.

But when i push this code to my **server** and i see this page on browser,
**noscript** tag moves into **body** tag like below..

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <noscript></noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

**Do you guess why it causes ??**
detail about our server environment is below.
There are some differences although i don't think it causes the problem...

【Environment】
Local
- XAMPP on my Mac
- Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) PHP/5.6.20

Server
- Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) PHP/5.6.15

========================================
and i also tested like below code.

```
echo <<< EOM
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <noscript></noscript>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
EOM;
```

it works on both environment.
so DOMDocument may be the culprit.. ? i don't know...
but i cannot use this code.. because of our framework.
so i still have to search the problem..

==============================================
and these are apache modules on our server.

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authn_alias_module (shared)
 authn_anon_module (shared)
 authn_dbm_module (shared)
 authn_default_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 authz_owner_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_dbm_module (shared)
 authz_default_module (shared)
 ldap_module (shared)
 authnz_ldap_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 logio_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 ext_filter_module (shared)
 mime_magic_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 usertrack_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 dav_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 info_module (shared)
 dav_fs_module (shared)
 vhost_alias_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 speling_module (shared)
 userdir_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 substitute_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_ftp_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_ajp_module (shared)
 proxy_connect_module (shared)
 cache_module (shared)
 suexec_module (shared)
 disk_cache_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 version_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
```

Comment: `<noscript>` tags are [invalid direct descendents of `<html>` tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/html), so it placed inside a `<body>` tag instead. If you want it to be inside the `<head>` tag, correct your HTML document.

Comment: >  Phylogenesis
Oops..
Sorry. i mistook the above code..
noscript tag is in head.

Comment: Specifically speaking,
i'm working on applying AMP to our site.
AMP code has noscript in head.
like this sample code..
https://www.ampproject.org/docs/get_started/create/basic_markup.html

Comment: [This looks good to me](http://ideone.com/rwox6T). I'm guessing the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: Before HTML 5, `<noscript>` was not allowed in `<head>`, so I suspected this might be error recovery but I'm using PHP 5.5.36 (older than your PHP), and cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: yes..
in localhost, all thing is OK.
so this code may be ok.
but on our server,
noscript is in body tag..

Comment: Is the `<noscript>` tag inside the `<body>` tag in the generated HTML or is it showing in the `<body>` tag after your browser builds the DOM? If the latter, which browser are you using to test this?

Comment: i tested on chrome.
and i also tested on command line using `curl -X get [URL]`.
both results are the same...
so i think the <noscript> tag inside the <body> tag is in the generated HTML..

Comment: You haven't done something like forgetting to update the actual template file on the server have you? Because I cannot get your problem to reproduce (even PHP 5.2 keeps the `<noscript>` element inside the `<head>` element).

Comment: i surely update all file on our server.
All things except noscript is same.

Comment: i downgrade local XAMPP PHP version to 5.6.15 to match to our server
but it still doesn't work...
so PHP version is not the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the answer by myself.
in my server, **libxml** version is **2.7.6**.
in my localhost, libxml version is **2.8.0**.
according to [this changelog](http://xmlsoft.org/news.html),
until 2.8.0, there was the bug of `HTML parser error with <noscript> in the <head>`
and this bug was fixed in release of version 2.8.0.
so i upgrade libxml on my server to 2.8.0, which fixed the problem!